# Copying all files from one directory to all directories under same parent directory

Tags: file-management

I have one parent directory /home/test and under that directory I have multiple directories.  The names are server{1..10} and one of them server3 has few files which I have copied from remote server.  I tried to use cp but it's not working for me.  Is there a way to copy all files or one file from server3 directory to rest of the server directories under /home/test.

Comment: was any of the answers useful?

Comment: I have chosen the loop one.  All were good for me but I can choose only one.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're after, the easiest way is a for loop:

```sh
myList="server1 server2 server4 server5 server6 server7 server8 server9 server10"
for myDir in $myList ; do cp server3/* $myDir/ ; done
```

Comment: It's possible to remove the list by using `ls` and `grep` in the `for` loop. For example `for dirs in $( ls testing | grep -v 3 ); do echo $dirs; done` results in `server1 server2 server4 server5 server6` omitting `server3` dir.

Comment: @Simply_Me - Yes of course, but I was going for quick and dirty.

Comment: cool, just wanted to point out it can be shorter :-)

Answer (score 1):

`cp` can handle multiple sources, but it can not handle multiple destinations.

You can use `echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -n 1 cp file1` this will copy `file1` to `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3`, for example.

Another modification is `echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -n 1 cp /home/test/server3/*` which will copy all of the files in a given directory to the echoed directories.

Additional solution, which is a bit shorter (w/o the need to enter directory names) is:

`ls -1 | grep -v server3 | xargs -n 1 cp server3/*`

Lastly, seems like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command)

Adding example for first solution:

```
# creating sample dir structure
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ mkdir server1
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ mkdir server2
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ mkdir server3
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ touch server3/test.one
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ touch server3/test.two
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ ls -R
./server1:
./server2:
./server3:
test.one  test.two

# executing solution
$ echo /home/shadowe/Desktop/server2/ /home/shadowe/Desktop/server1/ | xargs -n 1 cp /home/shadowe/Desktop/server3/*

# verifying solution
[shadowe@shadow Desktop]$ ls -R
./server1:
test.one  test.two
./server2:
test.one  test.two
./server3:
test.one  test.two
```

Adding example for second solution:

```
# showing directories structure and initial state
$ ls -R
server1:
server2:
server3:
test.one  test.two
server4:
server5:
server6:

# executing command
$ ls -1 | grep -v server3 | xargs -n 1 cp server3/*

# checking results
$ ls -R
./server1:
test.one  test.two
./server2:
test.one  test.two
./server3:
test.one  test.two
./server4:
test.one  test.two
./server5:
test.one  test.two
./server6:
test.one  test.two
```

As seen, both commands copied all of the files under `server3` to other directories, so it's a matter of preference and use case.

Comment: the `ls` solution will fail if `ls` decides to put more than one file for each row. Use `ls -1`

Comment: @pqnet thank you for the correction, I edited the answer.

Comment: no, not `-l` which stands for 'long', you have to use `-1` which stands for 'one'

Comment: @pqnet sorry I thought that's 1....

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to do this in one loop:

```
for i in ./server*; do cp ./server3/testfile* "${i}"; done
```

It will copy content of `server3` directory to each directory in current path.
This will also try to copy files to same directory but it only prints out that they are the same files and continues.

**Edit:**
To avoid nasty error messages you can enhance for loop with more specific wildcard. For example to skip `server3` use following: `server[1-24-9]`

Comment: Wouldn't this copy `server3` to itself as well? Could be time consuming if it's a large directory.

Comment: no, the cp command will complain that it can't copy a directory on itself

Comment: @pqnet thanks, I tested it after commenting and it's exactly as you said. Still inefficient in large directories.

Comment: For speed enhancement use specific wildcards (see edit)

Comment: it won't improve speed, as cp will bail out without doing anything if the source path and the destination path are equal, but it does not print nasty error messages. It could fail if there are spaces in the name of the directory though, thus maybe it could be a good idea to put `"$i"` instead of `${i}`

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It is only one `cp` call less.